# Which fallback is best when using rem as font-size unit in a responsive environement?

Tags: css, fonts, responsive-design

Recently I was wondering which fallback is best when using rem as font-size unit. Pixel seems appropriate, but if you want to change the global font-size in a specific media-query, every single px-based font-size needs to be redefined.

Here’s an example: Without any fallback for older browsers we could use

```
/* Mobile Styles */

html { font-size: 1rem; }
h1 { font-size: 2rem; }

/* Specific desktop styles */

@media only screen and (min-width: 992px) {
    html { font-size: 1.25rem; }
}
```

and all fonts would be enlarged by factor 1.25 on desktops. So far so good.

But as we need to provide IE8 with an alternative to rem, we have to use some sort of fallback, e.g.:

```
/* Mobile Styles */

html { font-size: 16px; font-size: 1rem; }
h1 { font-size: 32px; font-size: 2rem; }

/* Specific desktop styles */

@media only screen and (min-width: 992px) {
    html { font-size: 20px; font-size: 1.25rem; }
    h1 { font-size: 40px; font-size: 2rem; }
}
```

The downside: By doing so we need to redefine all font-size declarations in the desktop media-query again. The alternative would be to use em as fallback, but then the font size compounds.

Would be thrilled to hear your suggestions on this.

Comment: You're setting the font size of html in rem there. Now rem is actually short for _root em_, that is, the font size of the root element. So what you're doing here is set the font size of the root element (html) to 125% of itself. In other words, 1rem = 1.25rem. Not all browsers might like that. Anyway, to answer the question, the default stylesheets of most browsers define the sizes of h1 in em, not in rem, so why not keep with the standards? Just go with em.

Comment: Sorry, @MrLister, but you are completely missing my point. I know what rem is and what it does – it’s about the pixel fallback. Without the fallback, it wouldn't be necessary to define the font-size of the h1 in the media query again. (Edited the question to be more precise.)

Comment: Im not sure i understand the question, but if i do. You should define the base size to 62.8% , this way 1.0em is exactly 10px

Comment: It’s 62.5% that equals 10px, might be a typo ;-) But that’s not my point either, you still would have to redefine all font-size declarations.

Comment: Why not use percents for the media queries?

Comment: You mean like `html { font-size: 125%; }`? Nope, doesn't work. In IE8 the h1 would still be 32px without additional declaration of the bigger font-size in the desktop media query. My goal is to get something like the first example (the one without fallback) that works in IE8. Which might be impossible.

Comment: In that case, you could always create an IE8 only stylesheet.

Comment: Which ends in double maintenance. But it might be the only solution, yes.

Comment: @DanielRiemer My first point was that you set 1rem to be equal to 1.25rem, which I'm sure is considered an error under some circumstances. 1rem can't be equal to 1.25rem! And my second point was that you could easily set the font size of `h1` to 2em (or whatever ratio you want), because that's how the the browsers do it by default anyway, and then you won't need to repeat it in rem for each of the media queries.

Comment: @RonniSkansing Don't assume that the user's preferred size is 16px. It might not be.

Comment: Are we to assume you're polyfilling media queries for IE8 since it doesn't support them out of the box either?

Comment: @MrLister Thanks, I fixed the calculation error. The thing is that I want to replace all em units by rem not just in the html tag. Sizing fonts with rem is much easier, because it doesn’t depend on the parents element font-size (see more here: [http://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/font-size-with-rem](http://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/font-size-with-rem))

Comment: @BoltClock Using a polyfill might be an alternative solution, but if you have a lot of font-size declarations in your css, IE8 might explode, calculating itself to death. ;-)

Comment: I'm asking about polyfilling *media queries*, not the `rem` unit. If you're not polyfilling either one, then this question is mostly moot since there wouldn't be any point in providing fallback values within `@media` rules.

Comment: @BoltClock Sorry, misunderstood your comment. Yes, sure, I'm using respond.js to apply media queries in IE8.

Comment: @DanielRiemer But the link in your comment never sets a size in `rem` on the `<html>` element either. Because it knows not to equate 1.25rem with 1rem! Far better to leave `<html`> alone and set the `<body>` size instead.

Comment: @MrLister … true – but that's wrong ;-) See the CSS spec here: [http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#rem-unit](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#rem-unit) . It says: “Equal to the computed value of ‘font-size’ on the root element”, the root element is <html> not <body>.

Comment: Which is exactly what I said in my very first comment!! I'm done arguing.

Comment: Problem is, @MrLister, that you still don't get the core of my question. But that's okay :-)

Comment: @Mr Lister: Setting `font-size: 1.25rem` on the root element makes it 1.25x the size obtained by computing `font-size: medium`. The css3-values link above states this as well. Just an fyi.

Comment: I know that, but the thing is that rem is not a relative size. It is supposed to be the same throughout the document. Yes? Yes. So problem I have with the OP's practice is that, in the his bottommost piece of code, `2rem` is exactly twice the size of `1.25rem`.

Comment: But like I said, I'm done arguing.

Comment: Oh yeah, that. That's probably a mistake in the question. But anyway...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems best to use this polyfill https://github.com/chuckcarpenter/REM-unit-polyfill instead of fiddeling with fallbacks.

Answer (score 1):

well i've read all the comments but i don't see any answer to the question.... what's it's better as fallback when using rem units ? 
I think px is the best
why ?
because you go for rem units ok ? that means root element so that means will take it's size based on html { font-size: (define here a font size) right ? then if em is based on the parent element then if the parent element is a font-size of 18 and i want to set the font size to 24px to a h3 then it would be 24/18 instead of 24/16 ( default font size / other font size set to html tag) correct me if i'm wrong
So if the fallback is in em they will be calculated to the parent div and that means you might have different font sizes all over the place.

Later Edit:
I setting rem unit on html tag is wrong... but that's only my opinion.

Comment: Please write coherently. We have no idea what you're saying.

Comment: … and, as i mentioned in a previous comment, the root element is the <html>-tag, so that is definitely not wrong.

Comment: @Bogdan Maybe you can explain better than me why it's wrong. Why causing `2rem` to be twice `1.25rem` is not good.

Comment: because if you write 2rem in html / body tag it will mean 32px because you defined in relative units ( em / rem ) in this case rem unit which is relative to the root element ( html tag ) which by default it's set to 16px for most of the browsers so it will become 2rem = 32px ->> 32/16 1.25rem means 20px if you have your base size of 16px. on short when did i said you are wrong ? but you didn't explain him why and how.

Answer (score 1):

Why use a pollyfill and feed even more js into the slowest browsers at handling js?

You should use a preprocessor like sass. Can be used to just add ox fallback, but I like to make a typography section under `.lt-ie9` 
And use conditional comments to set that to my html tag.
As different stykesheets for ie is again to throw more http reqs at thr slowest browser.

Answer (score 0):

Font sizes are defined in points (preferably, since Gutenberg) or pixels. Ems are relative to the current font size, so using them *for* the font size is circular; using root ems ditto is ditto.

Comment: It's not circular; using an em value with `font-size` has it refer to the parent font size, or the browser/user default if there is no parent.

Comment: Using point as font-size unit in a pixel-based environment doesn't make any sense at all and is plain wrong. Exception: A print.css.