# Set multiple values for one css attribute

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is it possible to set two Values for a single attribute on a CSS ID, e.g.

> height: 12em; height: 12rem;

for a single id?
I know it's possible to do this with CSS, but I want to change the height via javascript, and have both values on one attribute, so that 'em' functions as a fallback for Browsers not supporting 'rem'.

Example:

```js
function updateHeight() {
  var testElem = document.getElementById("testId");
  testElem.style.height = "12em";
  testElem.style.height = "12rem";
  //testElem.style.height = "12em; 12rem;"; doesn't work, applies "12em"
}
```

```css
#testId {
  height: 8em;
  height: 8rem;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Test</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>

<body>
  <div id="testId">
    BlaBla
  </div>
  <button onclick="updateHeight()">Bla</button>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I guess you can write so, but the only applied version will be the last one, what you are trying to achieve ?

Comment: You can have hundreds of values, but if you use the same selector, only the last one will apply

Comment: I want a fallback, for Browsers not supporting 'rem'.

Comment: See this post, you can use a REM polyfill instead of worrying about fallbacks: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19480195/which-fallback-is-best-when-using-rem-as-font-size-unit-in-a-responsive-environe

Comment: According to [this article](https://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/font-size-with-rem) you can use both `px` and `rem` and any browser which cannot use `rem` will fallback to using `px`.

Comment: Isn't this really easy? Just add the styles to a class in your stylesheet, and add the class with javascript, just remember CSS specificity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a class instead

```js
function updateHeight() {
  var testElem = document.getElementById("testId");
  testElem.classList.add('high');
}
```

```css
#testId {
  height: 8em;
  height: 8rem;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}

#testId.high { /* remember that ID is more specific than class */
  height: 12em;
  height: 12rem;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Test</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>

<body>
  <div id="testId">
    BlaBla
  </div>
  <button onclick="updateHeight()">Bla</button>
</body>

</html>
```

Or if the value is dynamic, you'd probably have to insert a style tag to be able to support CSS cascading

```js
function updateHeight() {

  var value    = 12; // or something dynamic
  var styles   = '#testId {height: '+value+'em; height: '+value+'rem;}';
  var tag      = document.createElement('style');

  tag.innerHTML = styles;

  document.querySelector('head').appendChild(tag);

}
```

```css
#testId {
  height: 8em;
  height: 8rem;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Test</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>

<body>
  <div id="testId">
    BlaBla
  </div>
  <button onclick="updateHeight()">Bla</button>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can. This is defined by [CSS Cascade](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-cascade/#declared):

> Each property declaration [applied to an element](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-cascade/#filtering) contributes a
>   [***declared value***](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-cascade/#declared) for that property associated with the
>   element.
>
> These values are then processed by the [cascade](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-cascade/#cascade) to choose a single
>   “winning value”.
>
> The [***cascaded value***](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-cascade/#cascaded) represents the result of [the
>   cascade](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-cascade/#cascade): it is the [declared value](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-cascade/#declared-value) that wins the cascade (is
>   sorted first in the [output of the cascade](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-cascade/#output-of-the-cascade)).

Then, if you use

```css
height: 8em;
height: 8rem;
```

there will be 2 declared values for the property `height`: `8em` and `8rem`. The latter will will the cascade, becoming the cascaded value.

If some browser does not support one of them, the other one will be the only declared value, so it will win the cascade.

If some browser does not support any of them, the output of the cascade will be the empty list, and there won't be any cascaded value. The [specified](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-cascade/#specified) value will be the result of the [defaulting](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-cascade/#defaulting) processes (the [initial value](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-cascade/#initial-value) in this case, because `height` is not an [inherited property](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-cascade/#inherited-property)).

However, with JavaScript there is a problem. [`setProperty`](https://www.w3.org/TR/cssom-1/#dom-cssstyledeclaration-setproperty), used under the hood by camel case IDL properties in `.style`, uses the [set a CSS declaration](https://www.w3.org/TR/cssom-1/#set-a-css-declaration) algorithm, which overwrites existing declarations:

> 1. If *property* is a case-sensitive match for a property name of a CSS declaration in *declarations*, let *declaration* be that CSS
>      declaration.
> 2. Otherwise, append a new CSS declaration with the property name *property* to *declarations* and let *declaration* be that CSS declaration.

There are some workarounds:

- Use `cssText` instead of camel case IDL attributes:

  ```js
  testElem.style.cssText += "; height: 12em; height: 12rem; ";
  ```
- Check the style after setting it. If you get the empty string, it means it wasn't recognized.

  ```js
  testElem.style.height = "12rem";
  if(!testElem.style.height) testElem.style.height = "12em";
  ```
- Don't set the styles in the inline style declaration. Create a new stylesheet instead, or add some class to the element to trigger some CSS from an existing stylesheet.

Comment: That's right, I want to change the style with javascript, but than it only applies one style.

Comment: OK, I misunderstood the question. I have updated my answer.